# jsRender Rendering HTML

Tags: jquery, html, templates, jsrender

I'm using jsRender to render my data on html page. The data gets rendered perfectly. However, in some content items, HTML text (like hyperlink) appears as text. In jquery template, there is a way to render HTML by {{html. Is there anything similar available in jsRender? 
My code is as follows:

```
<p>
{{ =Status}}   //need to convert this to HTML so it should appear as hyperlink.
</p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The JsRender beta candidate is now out (see Boris' post from last night http://www.borismoore.com/2012/03/approaching-beta-whats-changing-in_06.html)

I wrote a quick fiddle to show how to render HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/NfUGB/

Basically, just use the {{>yourProperty}} tag to render it HTML encoding. Use {{:yourProperty}} to skip encoding.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <p>
    {{:foo}}
    </p>
    <ul>
    {{for testData}}
        <li>{{:name}} - {{:markup}} - {{>markup}}</li>
    {{/for}}
    </ul>
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

.

```
var vm = {
    foo: "names",
    testData: [
        {
            name: "John", 
            markup: "<span style='background: yellow'>John</span>"
        },
        {
            name: "Boris", 
            markup: "<span style='background: orange'>Boris</span>"
        }
    ]
};

$("#div1").html($("#template").render(vm));​
​
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `{{:Status}}` to generate HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at jsRender's source code I can see that the plugin converts the <, > and & characters into their HTML entities. Maybe you can try to change those lines from jsRender

```
escapeMapForHtml = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;"
},
```

to

```
escapeMapForHtml = {
},
```

Mind the security risk of inserting unchecked HTML from external sources!

EDIT: OK, checking the examples (esp. 03_no-encoding.html) brought another solution. So go ahead and undo my previously proposed change and try using

```
{{=Status!}
```

The exclamation mark should prevent jsRender from changing HTML

Comment: It doesn't work. It considers that HTML as string and puts within "". for example <p>"<a href="http://www.gmail.com" title="Click to open in a new window or tab" target="&#95;blank">http://www.gmail.com</a>"</p>

Comment: Maybe you should delete the first (non-working) part of your answer?

Comment: Then the comments won't fit the answer any more. I think I will keep it "as is"

Comment: Not a good idea to change those lines in JsRender. 
The previous syntax for esaping was {{=Status}} and for not escaping was {{=Status!}}. With the recent beta candidate, the syntax is {{>Status}} for escaping, and {{:Status}} for not escaping. The answer from John Papa below is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<p>
{^{ =Status}}   
</p>
```